# Inject javaScript inline code into header or before closing body tag section

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I would like to inject a script into one of the 3 page sections (Head, Bottom or DropedPosition) from a partial view.

I achieved this using the Html.Script helper when the script type use the reference.
The problem is to render a script that is **coming as a string and inject it in one of these sections**. The else statement is the part that its not working and I have no idea if it can be achievable from the partial view. Here is what I have:

```
@if (scriptType == "reference")
    {
        if (position == "Head")
        {        
            Html.Script(fileUrl, "head");
        }
        if (position == "DropedPosition")
        {        
            <text>
                <script src="@fileUrl" type="text/javascript"></script>
            </text>
        }
        if (position == "BeforeClosingBodyTag")
        {
            Html.Script(fileUrl, "bottom");
        }
    }
    else // script type is inLine
    {
        if (position == "Head")
        {
            Html.Script(inlineCode, "head");
        }
        if (position == "DropedPosition")
        {
            <text>
                <script type="text/javascript">               
                   @Html.Raw(inlineCode)
                </script>
            </text>
        }
        if (position == "BeforeClosingBodyTag")
        {        
            Html.Script(inlineCode, "bottom");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Assuming your script doesn't use `document.write` then why does it matter where it's "dropped"?

Comment: Script will be used as a custom Sitefinity CMS widget. When building a new form, in some cases will be needed to inject specific code that will run before or after certain scripts already in place on the page

Answer (score 0):

try to use else if, like this :

```js
if (scriptType == "reference")
    {
        if (position == "Head")
        {        
            Html.Script(fileUrl, "head");
        }
        else if (position == "DropedPosition")
        {        
            <text>
                <script src="@fileUrl" type="text/javascript"></script>
            </text>
        }
        else (position == "BeforeClosingBodyTag")
        {
            Html.Script(fileUrl, "bottom");
        }
    }
    else // script type is inLine
    {
        if (position == "Head")
        {
            Html.Script(inlineCode, "head");
        }
        else if (position == "DropedPosition")
        {
            <text>
                <script type="text/javascript">               
                   @Html.Raw(inlineCode)
                </script>
            </text>
        }
        else (position == "BeforeClosingBodyTag")
        {        
            Html.Script(inlineCode, "bottom");
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no issue with the conditions. The issue is related with the way I'm trying to render the string script into the right <header> or before </body> or in place sections of the page.